# Match group url parameter using Regular Expression?

Tags: javascript, url

My url looks like the below format:

```
http://www.example.com/?N=abc&Ntt=345999&Nr=AND(OR(AnalysisTechnique:acids),OR(ChemicalGroup:acetic%20acids))
```

I wanted to extract the Nr group parameter value like the below format:

```
AnalysisTechnique:acids, ChemicalGroup:aceticacids
```

Any help on this?

Comment: What have you done before? What are the possible Keywords besides `AND` and `OR`, or are they irrelevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That work for your given URL, but you should add more information for a better RegEx:

```
Nr=[\w()]+[(]([\w%]+:[\w%]+)[,\w()]+[(]([\w%]+:[\w%]+)
```

First group matches `AnalysisTechnique:acids` and second group matches `ChemicalGroup:aceticacids`

http://regex101.com/r/jZ1iJ1